# PhantomJs save webpage containing dynamic data as webpage

Tags: c#, phantomjs, html-to-pdf

I have used jQuery plugin to generate charts on screen along with dynamic data and notes.

I need to generate PDF of this webpage on button click.

I have tried to search good option but not able to find any proper one.

Right now I am trying to use phantomjs for this. It works for internet sites but not working for intranet sites.

I am continuously getting Unable to load address.

Can anyone suggest me the way to achieve this? Or any alternative way to generate PDF from html content (My html contains SVG, Javascript generated dynamic data too).

Code:

```
string serverPath = "C:\\Phantomjs\\bin\\phantomjs";
var phantomJS = new PhantomJS();
var outFile = Path.Combine(serverPath, "google2.pdf");

if (File.Exists(outFile))
    File.Delete(outFile);

try {
    phantomJS.Run(Path.Combine(serverPath, "rasterize.js"),
                new[] { "http://localhost:61362/HT.aspx?FNo=D1&PrNo=Dummy1&HtId=1033", outFile });
} finally {
    phantomJS.Abort();
}
```

The url is not working in this case. But if I take any internet hosted site, it works.

Comment: When you say the URL is not working in this case what do you mean ? Are you able to visit the page directly in your browser ?

Comment: Yes I am able to visit the page. If I try to refer a page of local IIS hosted site, it does not work with phantom js

Comment: Are you getting an HTTP error or is PhantomJS erroring out and calling your `phantomJS.Abort()`?